# How to filter for a range of values instead of exact values using the React-Admin-Firebase data provider on a React Admin project I'm working on?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, filter, react-admin

```
<FilterList
    label="Sales"
    icon={<AttachMoneyIcon />}
>
    <FilterListItem
        label="Best Sellers"
        value={{
            sales: 10
        }}
    />
    <FilterListItem
        label="Average Sellers"
        value={{
            sales_lte: 25,
            sales_gt: 10,
            sales: undefined,
        }}
    />
    <FilterListItem
        label="Low Sellers"
        value={{
            sales_lte: 10,
            sales_gt: 0,
            sales: undefined,
        }}
    />
    <FilterListItem
        label="Never Sold"
        value={{
            sales_lte: undefined,
            sales_gt: undefined,
            sales: 0,
        }}
    />
</FilterList>
```

The code snippet above has been taken from the **React-admin demo** site. They used a custom data provider that supports the suffix 'gte' and 'lte' to filter for values ***greater than equal to*** or ***less than equal to*** from the database. So, the `FilterListItem` `Component` has the prop called 'value' that takes key value pairs namely, **'sales_lte'** , **'sales_gte'**, to filter for sales ***'greater than equal to'*** or ***'less than equal to'*** . I want to know how to go about using the **React-admin-firebase Data Provider** to filter in a similar way.

[Link to React-admin-firebase Github](https://github.com/benwinding/react-admin-firebase)

Answer (score 1):

ra-data-firebase doesn't support greater_than or lower_than operators. Their filtering logic (see https://github.com/benwinding/react-admin-firebase/blob/fb58f58515ee45a43fa92a4acc0f262fe721366a/src/misc/arrayHelpers.ts#L42-L91) only tests for equality.

However, if you're willing to use some low-level Firebase APIs, this seems to be possible (see https://github.com/benwinding/react-admin-firebase/issues/161#issuecomment-729314143):

```
test("FirebaseClient with filter gte", async () => {
    const testDocs = [
      {
        title: "A",
        obj: {volume: 100},
      },
      {
        title: "B",
        obj: {volume: 101},
      },
      {
        title: "C",
        obj: {volume: 99},
      }
    ];
    const collName = "list-filtered";
    const collection = fire.db().collection(collName);
    await Promise.all(testDocs.map((doc) => collection.add(doc)));

    const client = new FirebaseClient(fire, {});
    const result = await client.apiGetList(collName, {
      filter: {
        collectionQuery: (c: firebase.firestore.CollectionReference) => c.where('obj.volume', '>=', 100) 
      },
      pagination: {
        page: 1,
        perPage: 10,
      },
      sort: {
        field: "obj.volume",
        order: "ASC",
      },
    });
    const third = result.data.length as any;
    expect(third).toBe(2);
  }, 100000);
```

Answer (score 1):

**I downloaded the React-admin-firebase npm souce  from their github page [React Admin Firebase Github](https://github.com/benwinding/react-admin-firebase) and modified the code as shown below and it works. I hard coded the filter names but we can easily make it so it accepts any filter names ending in '_gte' or '_lte'.**

**1.** Open the downloaded soure code in Vscode (or any other editor) and open the file called '*paramsToQuery.ts*' located in '*src/providers/lazy-loading/paramsToQuery.ts*'

**2.** Search for the function 'filtersToQuery' and make the changes accordingly as shown in the code below :

```
export function filtersToQuery(
  query: Query,
  filters: { [fieldName: string]: any }
): Query {
  Object.keys(filters).forEach((fieldName) => {
    if (fieldName === 'sales_gte') {
      query = query.where(fieldName.split('_')[0], '>=', filters[fieldName]);
    } else if (fieldName === 'sales_lte') {
      query = query.where(fieldName.split('_')[0], '<=', filters[fieldName]);
    } else {
      query = query.where(fieldName, '==', filters[fieldName]);
    }
  });

  return query;
}
```

3. Link it locally using npm to your project.